# Contrast adjustment for object detection and downfall of wrong application

Tags: image, object, detection, contrast

I have a general question about contrast adjustment, forgive me if it is too naive or general and please let me know if any correction is necessary.
Here is my question: When do we usually do contrast adjustment or contrast stretching in image processing or computer vision? In particular, when is it necessary to do contrast adjustments for object detection or segmentation? What are the downfall of contrast stretching, if not applied in the right situation? Can you give me a few examples as well?
Your answers are greatly appreciated!I

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can  classify algorithms that are related to images and videos processing int two categories: 
Image + video processing 
Where these algorithms can be used to enhance the quality of the image.

Computer vision:
These algorithms can be used to detect, recognize and classify objects.

The contrast adjustment techniques used to enhance the quality and the visibility of the image. 
Most of the time better input quality for computer vision algorithms can lead to better results. This is why most of cv algorithms use pre-processing steps to remove noise and improve the quality.